# SQL Query for 2 tables how to fill fields from first to second table

Tags: sql

I have two tables.
First has this structure:

```
ID / WEIGHT / CLICK
```

Second:

```
ID / SORT
```

And I calculate an variable `x = WEIGHT * n + CLICK * k` dynamically which I have to put in field SORT for second table.

How to make the query to fill var x from frist table to field SORT to second table.

Both tables have the same IDs.

Comment: First, tag your DBMS, languages are different. Second, what do you mean dynamically? what are n and k?

Comment: for example, n = 1 and k = 2. There`re variables too

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/5mdOGeVTkk4RQr first
http://joxi.ru/EA4RaVGUwwPJKm second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update s set sort=WEIGHT * n + CLICK * k
from first_table f
inner join second_table s on f.id=s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If id is auto increment:

```
 insert into tbl_Dep
 select WEIGHT * n + CLICK * k from table1
 where id = 1
```

If it's not an auto increment, add values also in the answer above.